# In Liferay 6.2, Save button doesn't work in Site Settings

Tags: java, liferay-6, java-ee-6

In Liferay 6.2, I want to change **Friendly URL** of a site (community). I go to `Control Panel/Sites` and select the desired site (community). On the left menu, I select `Configuration/Site Settings` and from the right menu, I select `Site URL` under `Basic information` group and modify the value of **Friendly URL**. But when I click on the `Save` button, nothing happens, even no error messages appear. Please see the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a clue by chance, so I share it to help others. I explored other tabs at the right button and found that there is an error in `Recycle Bin` tab, under `Advanced` group:

[image]

I must have changed the value of **Trash Entries Max Age** to *a value greater than or equal to 416.6666666666667* and unfortunately, this error hadn't appeared when I clicked `Save` button after modifying the **Friendly URL**. Anyway, after modifying **Trash Entries Max Age**, the action of `Save` button worked.